# Visual Studio C++ Access to path is denied

Tags: visual-c++, godot4, visual-c++-2022

I try to debug after successfully compiled dll to use ini Godot engine. I configured my launch.vs.json

```
{
 "version": "0.2.1",
 "defaults": {},
 "configurations": [
  {
   "type": "default",
   "project": "C:\\dev\\my\\godot\\Godot_v4.2.1-stable_win64.exe",
   "name": "Godot Game",
   "args": [ "--path", "C:\\dev\\my\\godot\\godotcpp\\test1\\godot-cpp-template\\demo" ]
  },

  {
   "type": "default",
   "project": "C:\\dev\\my\\godot\\Godot_v4.2.1-stable_win64.exe",
   "name": "Godot Editor",
   "args": [ "C:\\dev\\my\\godot\\godotcpp\\test1\\godot-cpp-template\\demo\\project.godot" ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Godot_v4.2.1-stable_win64.exe is in the correct path:

[image]

I can see the debug entries in VS++:

[image]

but when I click one of them I'm getting this error:

[image]

And it's not read only:

[image]

Comment: You can't execute a *directory* named Godot_v4.2.1-stable_win64.exe.  The launch.vs.json entry needs to be "project": "C:\\dev\\my\\godot\\Godot_v4.2.1-stable_win64.exe\\Godot_v4.2.1-stable_win64.exe".  Picking a sensible directory name would be advisable.

Comment: Please use a spelling checker, user63898. Every single one of your questions is riddled with errors that make it harder to help you (and you have 1,126 questions on this site).

Comment: If you quit naming folders with a .exe extension, you won't have this sort of issue. Directories are not executable, and adding a .exe extension to them is just totally ridiculous (and IMO pretty foolish).

Comment: @HansPassant write answer so that i can give you vi and stuff